# When Tcl library package is loaded?

Tags: tcl

When you create new interpreter it already contains Tcl package in it. Does somebody knows when this package is loaded? Is there any startup scripts that are calling package ifneeded Tcl  {....} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tcl package is loaded by the internal setup code run during the call to `Tcl_CreateInterp()` and can be considered to be definitions of the commands listed in the Tcl manual (except for those explicitly documented otherwise). The main use for it appearing in the package system is it lets you document what version of Tcl you require in a neat way:

```
package require Tcl 8.6
```

There's no `ifneeded` script for it; it's already present by definition (and has to be, as the `package` command is defined by it). At the C level, it's more useful. The Tcl package is what actually publishes Tcl's stub table, which allows Tcl to have an extremely stable ABI; the stub mechanism hides the gory details that change between minor versions and allows extension packages to be not linked to specific versions of Tcl, even if the Tcl interpreter is using a static build…

Comment: Thanks for answer. By the way now I have following problem. I have just ported my project from tcl8.4 to tcl8.6. But now I am getting error "...8.6/lib/tcl/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.4, need 8.6.2". Of course this is because I have missed something. Could you give me a hint how to find the reason of this issue?